# saving the content of contenteditable tag to database?

Tags: sql, html, jsp

can we save the changed content of contenteditable tag to database just by using JSP and HTML only? if yes, how?
I want to save the content of a cell of a table to my DB

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible but you should consider using servlet instead of doing DB access in you JSPs.

home.jsp

```
<html>
<body>
  <form action="updatedb.jsp" method="post">
   <input type="text" value="param1" name="para1"/>
   <input type="text" value="param2" name="para2"/>
   <input type="Submit" value="Update"/>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

update.jsp

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <sql:setDataSource var="dbsource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
       url="" user="root"  password="pass"/>
  <sql:update dataSource="${dbsource}" var="count">
    UPDATE product SET para1= ?, para2=?
   WHERE id='${param.id}'
   <sql:param value="${param.para1}" />
   <sql:param value="${param.para2}" />
  </sql:update>
</body>
</html>
```

take a look at [here](http://javaknowledge.info/jstl-1-1-simple-insert-update-delete-example/) for more info.